# Array Space Complexity

Tags: algorithm, memory, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I have a question that :

I have an array `"S"` which has `n` objects in it. also each object has `m` fields.
I want to save some of them in the another array like `"Q"` . I want to know that the space complexity of this easy method is `O(|Q|)`?

Answer (score 0):

The size of S it is `n*sum(sizeofeach(m of n))`

Then suppose you save r object where `r<n`

The size of q it is `r*(sum(sizeofeach(m of r))`

Comment: I do not think complexity is used for memory space, it is used for processing time.

Comment: for example the space complexity for merge sort is O(n) which is belong to memory space(I think)

Answer (score 0):

The space complexity is the amount of space required to store Q. Let `s` be the size of one element in Q, i.e. `s = size of all m fields`. The space complexity is `O(n*s)`. If all fields are the same constant size then you could say `O(n*m)`.